# Is this succulent coppertone?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image: Picture]

Please help with identification.

Answer (score 1):

It LOOKS like it might be a young succulent coppertone, but most of the ones I'm seeing are very vibrant, like this one:[succulent coppertone](https://www.etsy.com/listing/151032001/succulent-plant-coppertone-stonecrop).